# Need help on an algorithm that catches data on specific intervals from incoming serial data

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need help on creating an algorithm that catches data on specific intervals as demonstrated in the picture.

These are incoming messages from MCU and split in C# to acquire information about sensor data.
A data package is as follows;

```
:;10;123.123
```

- `:` is message package initiator
- `10` is distance
- `123.123` is sensor reading

Message splitting happens with below code;

```
else if(s[0] == ':')
{
  string[] a = new String[3];
  string[] z = s.Split(';');

  for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
  {
    switch (i)
     {
       case 0:
           a[0] = z[i + 1];
           temp_distance = int.Parse(a[0]);
           break;
       case 1:
           a[1] = z[i+1];
           temp_dimension = float.Parse(a[1]);
           break;
      }
   }
}
```

A function needs to be called every specific interval as given in the picture.[image]

any help is appreciated.

Comment: So if `distance % 50 == 0` you need to call that function?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Basically yes.

Comment: Does it answer your question? ;-)

Comment: I know it's very simple but currently i am experiencing a brain freeze :). Tried with a counter, wasn't successful.

Comment: `if (int.parse(s.Split(';')[1]) % 50 == 0) { do_something }`

Comment: @Stef how could i reference the previous and current sensor readings in this do_something part? Could you please advise?

Comment: Your code shows how you are storing only one reading into the temp variables. So, how do you want to refer to the previous one? Is the code shown in a (not visible) loop? Are you adding these readings to a list? Please, show the whole relevant code.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes currently i am not storing the previous sensor data anywhere. This is the whole code for now, will add storing, function calls according to suggestions.

Comment: I need to to see more code. The code snippet you are showing us gives not enough clues. Currently it is not clear what you are doing with this data. What is the `a` array needed for?

Comment: I also would like to know what the array `a` is for. I don't think Olivier is "bullying"; if anything, they took some time to try to understand your problem and to ask you questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to call a function on each 5(for example) records you received from the port. if it is, In my opinion you should create a class for your sensor data. then after receiving a complete block of your data, create its object and add it to a List. Then you can sort list by distance field and when your List.Count is proper for calling your function, you can call it and pass list to it.

Comment: I need to use the mentioned values in runtime with on charts. function i am trying to call will calculate a result with referenced sensor data and update the chart series on runtime. So i can create a list, class and evaluate data after reading is completed but, it doesn't really what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit weird. The switch-statement inside the for-loop basically undoes the looping, resulting in each case being executed once. I suggest dropping the loop and the switch-statement:

```cs
else if(s[0] == ':;')
{
    string[] z = s.Split(';');
    temp_distance = int.Parse(z[1]);

    if (temp_distance % 50 == 0) { // When distance = 0, 50, 100, 150 ...
        temp_dimension = float.Parse(z[2]);

        func(prev_distance, prev_dimension, temp_distance, temp_dimension);

        // Remember the values for the next iteration.
        prev_distance = temp_distance;
        prev_dimension = temp_dimension;
    }
}
```

I assume that this code is embedded in an outer loop reading the lines from the input (this is not apparent from your code). Therefore, you can reference the previous values by storing them to another set of variables before assigning the new values .

I dropped the array `a` as it is not required for these operations; however, you might have to re-add it, if you need it somewhere else (this is not apparent from your code either).